# Why SetMenuInfo doesn't work under Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi

When I use SetMenuInfo to change background color of MenuBar it works under Windows XP,but doesn't work under Windows 7.What is the reason?How can I solve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a theming issue. If you switch to classic theme, the background colour change will probably start working again but the normal default themes don't allow this option to work. I think a few controls have changed in this way with theming. I'm surprised you don't see the problem in XP though - I thought that had themes too, although it is a very long time since i've used XP.

Comment: No, XP does not theme the menus, all it added was "flat menus" (1 pixel border around the selection in another color, and XP itself gets that wrong in several places. See http://windowssucks.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/does-this-make-me-look-flat/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set MainMenu to OwnerDraw and your effect will take place.